# Impossible to turn off browser CHROME autocomplete

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm using Google Autocomplete address API (here the [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform))

I'm using angular2 and this is the code

HTML

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="post">
   <input autocomplete="false" name="address" type="text" style="display:none;">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="shippingAddress">Address*</label>
       <input id="shippingAddress" name="address" type="text"  autocorrect="off" [(ngModel)]="shipping.Address1" (blur)="checkIndirizzo()" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off" class="form-control" #search [formControl]="searchControl">
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

I tryied also this

```
   <input autocomplete="false" name="address" type="text" style="display:none;">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="shippingAddress">Address*</label>
       <input id="shippingAddress" name="address" autocomplete="off" type="text"  autocorrect="off" [(ngModel)]="shipping.Address1" (blur)="checkIndirizzo()" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off" class="form-control" #search [formControl]="searchControl">
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The google autocomplete works perfectly, but the browser autofill covers the dropdown of google maps autocomplete. All I wanna do is to disable the browser autocomplete on this text input but I'm becoming crazy.
I read some solutions but no one works.

The only solution that worked is to set the input of type password and set

```
autocomplete="new-password"
```

but the problem is that I see dots when I write in the textbox and this is not good.

I tryied also with the hidden input field but nothing to do.
I'm using Chrome v 63.0.3239.84

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried `autocomplete="off"` directly on the `<input>`?

Comment: @Xufox yes, it's the first thing that I tryed

Answer (score 0):

Chrome analyzes the text before the input and will trigger its autofill UI based on the words. I've found that putting the label after the input fixes the issue. I keep an empty label above to keep the space and then set `position: absolute;` on the label after

I've included a sample below

https://codepen.io/anthonyholmes/pen/YYvXEa